# SQL - transform the column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I execute the query:

```
select Number,
       Name,
       [Date and Time],
       Value
from Source;
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But I want this result:

[image]

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: where's your query and which dbms?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: i add code , i use sql

Comment: What's the expected result if a 4 suddenly shows up in the Value column? (Do you want another column named 4 in the result-set?)

Comment: no, I have only value 1,2,3

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ISO/ANSI. There are many different products implementing the language, more or less standard compliant. Which product are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql managment studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `COALESCE(MAX(CASE` you can get your expected result.

Sample execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE (Number INT, Name VARCHAR (100), DateAndTime VARCHAR (20), Value INT);

INSERT INTO @Source(Number, Name, DateAndTime, Value) VALUES
(1, 'Tom', '1.5.2016 11:29', 1),
(1, 'Tom', '2.5.2016 10:45', 2),
(2, 'Angelina', '7.5.2016 11:36', 1),
(3, 'Fibi', '1.5.2016 11:34', 2),
(3, 'Fibi', '1.5.2016 11:56', 3);

SELECT Number, Name,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 1 THEN DateAndTime END), '') AS [1],
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 2 THEN DateAndTime END), '') AS [2],
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 3 THEN DateAndTime END), '') AS [3]
FROM @Source
GROUP BY Number, Name
ORDER BY Number
```

Result:

```
Number  Name        1               2               3
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Tom         1.5.2016 11:29  2.5.2016 10:45  
2       Angelina    7.5.2016 11:36      
3       Fibi                        1.5.2016 11:34  1.5.2016 11:56
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , that's it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` expressions to return the date/time values in different columns:

```
select Number, Name,
       max(case when Value = 1 then [Date and Time] end) as [1],
       max(case when Value = 2 then [Date and Time] end) as [2],
       max(case when Value = 3 then [Date and Time] end) as [3]
from Source
group by Number, Name
```

The `GROUP BY` is there to return a name's all values in one single row. (**Note**: Only one value 1, 2, 3 per name will be returned!)

Comment: i got two row for Tom, first for value 1 and second for value 2... I want all in one row...